# CSS updates appear after delay

Tags: uploads, css, cache, ftp

I am using an FTP client to download/edit/upload CSS files of my child theme. Typically that worked smoothly and updates were seen after refreshing the page in the browser immediately.

However, on my current fresh wordpress install, I see changes in my CSS only after a few minutes, which makes the whole process really annoying. I don't quite know what I am doing wrong.

Here some details:

- I use a child-theme which uses the twentythirteen theme as a parent.
- It's definitley not a browser cache issue, since I work on chrome incognito mode with the dev-console opened (and enabled *Disable cache (while DevTools is open)* checkbox)
- One strange thing I observer is, that, when accessing the child theme's CSS file directly in the browser it appears differently sometimes. I suspect, Wordpress is somehow accessing the CSS file and if there was a change, it caches the file and from then on returnes a minified version of the CSS. Maybe this is the root cause of the error. This is what the file actually looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJDcv.png This is what the *same* file most of the times looks like when accessed via the browser directly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW2TG.png
- This is the excerpt of the child-theme's functions.php which shows how the child-theme's style is included. Maybe I am doing something wrong here: http://pastebin.com/0MRjTTjf

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Have you tried doing CTRL+F5 when you refresh?

Comment: yes. as i said: it's definitely not a browser cache issue.

Comment: Sounds like varnish (or a similar proxy cache) - this is at the hosting level, not a problem you can solve with code

Comment: but the different display of the style.css file as shown in above screenshots (http://i.imgur.com/TAUYjGR.png and http://i.imgur.com/QnycJ2r.png) leads me to belife that Wordpress is doing something here and not some hosting-cache? Or can someone explain to me why the file is displayed differently?

Comment: Do you have any cache plugin installed?

Comment: question is already answered. see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Webhoster has enabled `mod_pagespeed` by default. I had to turn this off via entering `ModPagespeed off` in my `.htaccess` file. Abhik also pointed to this in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669099/wordpress-css-updates-appear-after-delay?noredirect=1#comment55112071_33669099).

Comment: Can you post your htaccess file? I have this issue also.